# Kuranishi Family as Local Moduli space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, deformation-theory

Let $X$ be a compact complex manifold. People always refer the Kuranishi family of $X$ as the "local moduli space" of the moduli space of complex structures on $X$.

I am confused with this terminology. When I look at the 2-torus case $T^2$. It is known that the moduli space of complex structure on $T^2$ is given by the quotient
$$\mathbb{H}/SL(2,\mathbb{Z}),$$
where $\mathbb{H}$ is the upper-half space and $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ acts on it by Mobius transform. However, the Kuranishi space of $T^2$ is simply given by the unit disk (or $\mathbb{H}$), because the Maurer-Cartan element is given by
$$td\bar{z}\otimes\frac{\partial}{\partial z}.$$
Hence for different $t$'s, the corresponding elliptic curves can be isomorphic.
So, how should I interpret the Kuranishi family as the "local moduli space"?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm sorry I can't help much with this question (I don't know some of the concepts you're using), but is it possible that the *Kuranishi family* of $X$ is actually the *Teichmuller space* of $X$? The moduli space is a quotient of the Teichmuller space. For a little information on this, see [this delightful paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.352.9401&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Comment: Never mind. At least your comment leads me to read the following paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.1368.pdf. Thank you anyway!